# Python Package Creation

Tags: python, package

I have a package i am trying to create.  The directory hierarchy looks like this.

```
Package/
    __init__.py
    Part1/
        __init__.py
        item.py
        load_items.py
    Part2/
        __init__.py
        section.py
    Part3/
        __init__.py
        mappings/
            file1.txt
            file2.txt
            ...
            file10.txt
        map.py
        unmapped.txt
```

I have some other file main.py that is not in the package and inside I have put

```
import Package
print(dir(Package))
```

The output from this is

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

however I was expecting to see "Part1", "Part2", and "Part3" in this list.  I also tried

```
print(Package.Part1)
```

and I got an attribute error: Package has no attribute Part1.

This is the first package I have made and I am also unsure why `__init__.py` is needed in every directory?  Or perhaps this is wrong and it isn't.  I've read a bunch of the other questions on stack overflow but none of them have really helped me understand.  Basically, I'm looking for whether my package is structured correctly and why when I do dir(Package) the parts of it are not listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir` return all variables and methodes of an object

for example :

```
class Person:
  name = "John"

  def foo(self):
        return "Hello"

print(dir(Person))

>> out 
    [... 'foo', 'name']
```

---

If you want to list all directories and files in a directory, you can do

```
import os
os.listdir(path)
```

---

You can retrieve the path of an installed package with `importlib`

Here is an example with the `requests` package

```
import importlib.util
path = importlib.util.find_spec("requests").origin

>> out : 
    ..../python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'
```

---

By combining both method, we can list all directories of our package

```
import importlib.util
import os

path = importlib.util.find_spec("requests").origin

# remove the "/__init__.py" part
path = path[:-11]
os.listdir(path)

>> out : 
    ['cookies.py',
     'auth.py',
     'sessions.py',
      ...
     ]
```

---

The `__init__.py` is required in each directory.
This file tells your python interpreter that the folder is a python package. Without it, you won't be able to import the package in an other folder.